# CSS fix to align container-fluid container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get a simple center alignment working. At the moment I am not able to get it working.

[image]

Code to this is quite simple, it uses bootstrap 4.x

base_nologin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />

  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Font awesome CSS -->
  <link href="/vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="/css/login.simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
  <!-- All other header files -->
  <link href="/css/login.style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  {% block moreHeadFiles %}
  {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <!-- Navbar -->
      {% include "_navbar_nologin.html" %}
      <!-- Page Content -->
      <main>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          {% block content %}
          {% endblock %}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="bg-light border-right card-footer fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="m-0 text-center text-black">
        Test
      </p>
      <p class="m-0 text-center text-black">Copyright &copy; 2020</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- All javascript -->
  <!-- jquery -->
  <script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" {% if nonce_value is defined %}nonce="{{ nonce_value|safe }}" {% endif %}>
  </script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    {% if nonce_value is defined %}nonce="{{ nonce_value|safe }}" {% endif %}></script>
  <!-- All other scripts -->
  {% block moreScripts %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

The flask jinja2 templates render the {% block content %} {%endblock} with the following

```
{% extends "base_nologin.html" %}
{% block moreHeadFiles %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="pt-4 container">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="card text-center bg-light mb-3">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="muted">Login</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form id="login-form" class="justify-content-center" method="POST" role="form">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="email">Username: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input pattern=".{1,35}" size="35" title="6 to 35 characters" type="text" name="username" tabindex="1"
                class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Username" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="password">Password: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input pattern=".{12,48}" size="48" title="12 to 48 characters" type="password" name="password" tabindex="2"
                class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
              <div class="float-left">
                <a href="{{ url_for('forgot_password') }}"><small>Forgot your password?</small></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="align-items-center">
              <input type="submit" name="login-submit" tabindex="3" class="btn btn-login btn-outline-success"
                value="Log In">
            </div>
          </div>
          {% if errmsg is defined %}
          <p style="color: red"> {{ errmsg }} </p>
          {% endif %}
          {% if msg is defined %}
          <p style="color: green"> {{ msg }} </p>
          {% endif %}
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <p>Don't have an account?</p>
              <a href="{{ url_for('create_new_user') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Register now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block moreScripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

_navbar_nologin.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
</nav>
```

login.simple-sidebar.css

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: .80rem;
}
```

login.style.css

```
.center {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper img {
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
}

input[type="number"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.abs {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I just want to align the login box to center of the page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would place an element on the page to act as a 'container' for the login box, give it a height of like 100vh or 80vh (you decide, whatever works), and then for the actual login element make it have auto margins:
`margin: auto.`

That should cause to to be positioned in the center of the page, but note the fixed footer and nav bar will not be accounted for in any sort of css alignment stuff (because they're fixed and won't affect page flow)

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you talking about a div? I already have <div class="pt-4 container">. Is this what you are referring to? This is in 
```
{% extends "base_nologin.html" %}
{% block moreHeadFiles %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="pt-4 container">
```